# How to merge duplicate child record in nested json structure?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have Variants and subvariants and this sub variants are those entities which will come under different tests.

Now i want to remove duplicate sub variants from nested child object from the json structure.

**Json structure:**

```
[
  {
    "ParentVariantName": "Variant1",
    "TestList": [
      {
        "TestId": 100,
        "Version": 0,
        "SubVariantsList": []     
        ]
      },
      {
        "TestId": 101,
        "Version": 1.0,
        "SubVariantsList": [
          {
            "SourceSubVariantModel": {
              "Id": 69,
              "Name": "Abc",
              "DiffPerc": 100
            },
            "TargetSubVariantModel": {
              "Id": 70,
              "Name": "Pqr",
              "DiffPerc": 200
            }
          },
          {
            "SourceSubVariantModel": {
              "Id": 70,
              "Name": "Pqr",
              "SourceValue": 200
            },
            "TargetSubVariantModel": {
              "Id": 71,
              "Name": "Xyz",
              "TargetValue":300
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "TestId": 247,
        "Version": 3.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      },
      {
        "TestId": 248,
        "Version": 4.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      },
      {
        "TestId": 249,
        "Version": 5.0,
        "SubVariantsList": [] 
      },
      {
        "TestId": 250,
        "Version": 6.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For eg:in above json structure for **TestId = 101**:

`Id 70 is repeating 2 times and so i want to merge duplicate records` and want output like this:

**Expected Output:**

```
[
  {
    "ParentVariantName": "Variant1",
    "TestList": [
      {
        "TestId": 100,
        "Version": 0,
        "SubVariantsList": []     
        ]
      },
      {
        "TestId": 101,
        "Version": 1.0,
        "SubVariantsList": [
          {
             "Id": 69,
             "Name": "Abc",
             "DiffPerc": 100
          },
          {
             "Id": 70,
             "Name": "Abc",
             "DiffPerc": 200
          },
          {
             "Id": 71,
             "Name": "Abc",
             "DiffPerc": 300
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        "TestId": 247,
        "Version": 3.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      },
      {
        "TestId": 248,
        "Version": 4.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      },
      {
        "TestId": 249,
        "Version": 5.0,
        "SubVariantsList": [] 
      },
      {
        "TestId": 250,
        "Version": 6.0,
        "SubVariantsList": []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

This is what i am trying:

```
 foreach (var item in data)
            {
                foreach (var testList in item.TestList)
                {
                    foreach (var cdList in testList.SubVariantsList)
                    {
                        if (list.Count == 0)
                        {
                             list.Add
                                 (
                                    new
                                    {

                                    }
                                 )
                        }    
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: in your expected JSON you have not merged the duplicates, you have just neglected one. On what condition do you decide to neglect the duplicates?

Comment: @Reddy :See my expedted json output you will see that under TestId 101 i have 2 Id with value 70 and in my expected output i have merged that 2 records because both are same.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a class for your new `SubVariantsList` entries if you haven't done so and instantiate it when populating a new list for the updated `SubVariantsList`.

In the sample below I defined `Model` as such a class. It also defines `UpsertToList()` method to help filling the list without duplication.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string json = @"
[
  {
    ""ParentVariantName"": ""Variant1"",
    ..... Removed to save space. Insert your input JSON here with " changed to "" ....
";
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);
            foreach (var item in data)
                foreach (var test in item.TestList)
                {
                    var list = new List<Model>();
                    foreach (var pair in test.SubVariantsList)
                    {
                        Model.UpsertToList(list, pair.SourceSubVariantModel);
                        Model.UpsertToList(list, pair.TargetSubVariantModel);
                    }
                    test.SubVariantsList = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(list);
                }

            Console.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Model
    {
        public int Id;
        public string Name;
        public int DiffPerc;

        public static void UpsertToList(List<Model> list, dynamic sourceObject)
        {
            var item = list.FindLast(model => sourceObject.Id == model.Id);
            if (item == null)
                list.Add(new Model(sourceObject));
            else
                item.Update(sourceObject);
        }

        Model(dynamic sourceObject)
        {
            Id = sourceObject.Id;
            Update(sourceObject);
        }

        void Update(dynamic sourceObject)
        {
            Name = sourceObject.Name;
            var diffPerc = sourceObject["DiffPerc"];
            if (diffPerc == null)
                diffPerc = sourceObject["SourceValue"];
            if (diffPerc == null)
                diffPerc = sourceObject["TargetValue"];
            if (diffPerc != null)
                DiffPerc = diffPerc;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I used Json.Net so you may need to `Install-Package Newtonsoft.Json`